# Visual Studio 2017 Access Denied When Creating Self Signing Test Cert

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, windows-installer, clickonce

Specs-  I am running VS2017 Enterprise Edition on a Windows 10 machine. I have a simple .DLL I will be updating from a web server and externally referencing into a piece of software that belongs to another company.  I normally use Inno Setup but I wanted to take advantage of ClickOnce.  However, when I try to make a test certificate I get an error message. I have found some information to indicate it is a permissions issue. I am running it as administrator and I am the admin.

The Issue- Access is denied.(Expection from HRESULT: 0x80070005(E_ACESSDENIED))

VS2017 is running in Administrator mode and my client has full rights.

I am able to import my companies certificate from file but I do not want to use it.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.  If you are working remotely(RDP), you must be on the work network to create the cert. I would assume this will work if you use a Cisco as well. I brought my machine to work to show my boss the issue and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

Exit Visual Studio and reopen ‘As Admin’

Comment: "VS2017 is running in Administrator mode and my client has full rights. "-As I posted already, I am running it as the admin and on a client that is an administrator This is not the answer.

Comment: Worked for me... I wonder if it has anything to do with my project residing in the OneDrive folders, as I don't recall having to previously do this.

Comment: Thank you, but can not believe that VS does not have dialog message for this.